# How can Change the load order of stylesheets so that apptrain module css loads before custom.css and site-specific.css

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, local.xml

I have installed apptrian in my site. Now I have to change the load order of stylesheets so that apptrain module css loads before custom.css and site-specific.css. I am working in local. Where can I change the load order and how can i test it. Any helps are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your theme `local.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <update handle="add_css_first" />
    </default>

    <add_css_first>
        <action method="addCss" block="head">
            <file>apptrain/module/custom.css</file> <!-- Change this with actual css path -->
        </action>
    </add_css_first>
</layout>
```

This will add your specified css at top of others.